# Can I define a type inside a class in Object Pascal?

Tags: types, pascal, delphi

Here's an example (which is not working):

```
type
    menu = class
        private
            menu_element = RECORD
                id: PtrUInt;
                desc: string;
            end;
        public
            procedure foo();
    end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. But since you want to declare a type, you must type a valid [type expresssion](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refch3.html)

```
type menu = class
  private
    type menu_element = RECORD
      id: PtrUInt;
      desc: string;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: That construct is Delphi 2006+ or FPC 2.6+

Comment: I was assuming the OP to use FPC with the objfpc dialect. Since it's open-source it's rare to see someone using an old version of the compiler. But it's right that it could another compiler.

Comment: If you assumed FPC, then an older and more direct solution is possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Free Pascal accepts this if you change the "=" to a ":".  Fields are declared with ":", types with "="

```
{$mode Delphi}
type
    menu = class
        private
            menu_element : RECORD
                id: PtrUInt;
                desc: string;
            end;
        public
            procedure foo();
    end;

procedure menu.foo;
begin
end;


begin
end.
```

Turbo Pascal and Delphi (and FPC's before 2.2) forbid this. Free Pascal reinstated this old (Classic Pascal) behaviour because of Apple dialects.

Comment: Delphi does not forbid nested types (classes, records, enumerations, etc.):
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Nested_Type_Declarations

Comment: That is something different. That is still a separate type declaration ( a separate block just within the scope in the class), not in place as the example shows. Compare the two sources.

Comment: I'm going off the question asked (which I assume your answer is attempting to answer), which was can you define a type inside a class in Object Pascal. Which you can. Are you attempting to answer a different question or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, you answered the title, I answered focussing on the code.